# How to Open two Navigation Drawer from Right side on AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

```
    The above code  is for xml changes.

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.ensivo4.mobileapp.SubActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<include
    layout="@layout/appbarmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_left_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:accessibilityLiveRegion="none">
    <include layout="@layout/navheadermain"/>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/inner_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_right_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <include layout="@layout/rightdrawer"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/login_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_myaccount"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_myaccount" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is  for Inner Navigation Drawer for MyAccount Navigation Drawer .I have first LoginPage  and second Is My Account on rightDrawer .openInnerDrawer() is called while clicking on login button which is available on loginPage drawer.

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);         // this is Main Drawwwer For left and right
    rightNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_right_view);  //   this is for right Drawer

    private void openInnerDrawer() {
    innerDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.inner_drawer_layout);
    innerDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    innerDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  //  innerDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    LoginNavigationView =(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.login_navigation_view);
    LoginNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_Orders) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_Favorite_list) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_Address) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_track_my_order) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_coupons) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_saved_cards) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_Setting) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                closeInnerDrawer();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    //innerDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this.But problem not resolve yet plz chk my coad .Its not give result as i want

Comment: no that is not changes . i ll update my changes

Comment: Plz chk my changes for xml and activity.

Comment: On the first drawerlayout I have a Login options.I want while clicking on login button Second drawerlayout  ll  open.

Comment: I already tried that. plz chk xml code.For  Three navigation Drawer  First in left Second And Thired  on Right

Comment: I'm starting to think that we're talking about different behaviors, here. The post I linked is meant to open a second drawer inside the first drawer while the first one is already open. I think you mean that you just want the right drawer to change contents altogether, opening only one of the right-side drawers at a time. Is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly . That i want

Comment: Ah, OK, then ignore that post. I misunderstood your question. What you want can be done much more simply. Use one `DrawerLayout`, put both of your `NavigationView`s inside a `FrameLayout` that has `layout_gravity="right"`, and then just use `setVisibility()` to hide/show the `NavigationView`s as needed before opening the drawer. You follow me?

Comment: yes i m trying.

Comment: I used Two relative Layout on Same Navigation  Drawer.Show/hide Relative layout did the thing for me.  Thanks for help,

Comment: No problem. Sorry to have misled you at first. I mistakenly assumed you were going for the inner drawer pattern, as that's usually what people ask about when using two drawers on one side. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Two navigation drawer will cause a lot of problems and lot of code. I use [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)  Library for all my projects. You can also use it for two navigation drawer without any problem